# create an Audio only rendition - 8KHz 16-bit little endian uncompressed.wav

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to convert a file which has 16 channels as below from pcm_s24le to pcm_s16le and want to put it in wav container.

When I tried to convert it, it is converting for the only first stream and other 15 streams are missing. I need have all channels in my output with s16le in wav container.

Code used: ffmpeg -f s24le -ar 48000 -ac 16 -i inputfile   -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 16   output.wav

Input file:
  Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Picture
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 0
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 1
    Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 2
    Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 3
    Stream #0:5: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 4
    Stream #0:6: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 5
    Stream #0:7: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 6
    Stream #0:8: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 7
    Stream #0:9: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 8
    Stream #0:10: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 9
    Stream #0:11: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 10
    Stream #0:12: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 11
    Stream #0:13: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 12
    Stream #0:14: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 13
    Stream #0:15: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 14
    Stream #0:16: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010101010D1313000000417264656E646F0117124A5702366C00
      track_name      : Audio 15

Output file:

Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 01:52:03.57, bitrate: 12288 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, hexadecagonal, s16, 12288 kb/s

Comment: You'll need to use amerge filter.

Comment: again it creates single stream with 12 channels but i need 12 streams.     
 Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 12 channels (FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR+FLC+FRC+BC+SL+SR+TC), s16, 9216 kb/s

Comment: WAVS can only store one stream.

Comment: ok, thank you.. but i have 16 channels how does it works?

Comment: You will have to map all of the streams with `-map 0` and use a different output container such as MKA. Or output each stream to individual WAV files.